Xamarin iOS Method Not Found in AppStore release only
I have xamarin forms app that works totaly fine in debug mode (on emulator and ipad).
When I distrubute it to TestFlight i am getting:
Method Not Found: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.NegotiationResponse
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.NegotiationResponse(System.ReadOnlySpan'1)
I am using:

Latest version of xCode and Visual Studio (I use Windows)
Xamarin.Forms 5.0.0.2662
Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client 8.0.4

I always clear bin/obj before build. I ve tries all linking behaviours and problem still occures. Here is my current .csproj configuration:

I have the same problem with System.Formats.ASN1. Do you have any ideas what is wrong? As i mentioned everything works fine in debug mode.

Have you tested on the iOS device in release mode? Does the error still happen?

You may also check Linker Behavior or the Xamarin.iOS Interpreter

Hi. Sorry for late reply. I tried all liker behavior with and without Interpreter and I got the same same error. I cant lunch it on iPad in release mode but in debug it works fine.

Here is a similar thread on StackOverflow Exception caught Method not found:Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.NegotiationResponse on iOS.

Setting packagereference in .csproj resolved the issue.
<PackageReference Include="System.Buffers">
    <Version>4.5.1</Version>
    <IncludeAssets>none</IncludeAssets>      
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="System.Memory">
    <Version>4.5.4</Version>
    <IncludeAssets>none</IncludeAssets>      
</PackageReference>

